# printing $GLOBALS private static property not showing

Tags: php

I am practicing the singleton pattern using several examples. My code so far:

```
class LimitedEditionBuggati {
    private $props = array(
                            'speed'     => 256,
                            'cylinders' => 18,
                            'color'     => 'metalic silver',
                            'hp'        => 1200,
                            'price'     => 5000000,
                            'vin'       => 'the one'
                           );
    private static $instance;

    private function __construct(){}

    public static function instance() {
        if( empty($instance) ) {
            return new LimitedEditionBuggati();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function getProperty( $property ) {
        return $this->props[$property];
    }
}

$myCar = LimitedEditionBuggati::instance();
```

How come the `private static $instance` does not get printed using `print_r( $GLOBALS )`?

Comment: Why would it be printed again?

Comment: Google: Why not to use singletons in php (use Dependency Injection). Why not to use statics (global state, hard coupling, poor code re-use). This will eventually lead you to write your code with: no new calls, no statics and no singletons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How come the `private static $instance` does not get printed using `print_r( $GLOBALS )`?

Even though static class variables are variables that exist once and only once - as it is similar with global variables - they are not globally *visible* through `$GLOBALS` because they are not global variables in PHP.

You can compare that with static variables inside a function (perhaps a better known concept for you):

```
function my_function()
{
    static $variable = 1;
}

my_function();
print_r($GLOBALS);
```

Even though the static variable `$variable` exists once and only once - similar to a global variable, it is just, that it is not visible in `$GLOBALS`.